# Is it a good practice to use objects as keys in JS maps?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**TLDR:** I have custom objects with unique IDs and I want to create `Map()` with these objects as keys. Should map's keys be these objects themselves or is it better to use object ID as a key?

**Full question:**

For example I have a `Room` object that contains a `Map()<personID, Person>`, where `personID` is an int and `Person` is a custom object.

```
class Room { 
    constructor()
    {
        // Map personID to Person
        // @type {Map<Integer, Person>}
        this._persons = new Map();
    }
}
```

Each person can have a custom nickname for other users in the room and that is achieved by having a `Map<personkey, nickname>` in each `Person` object. So the question is whether `personkey` should be `personID` or a `Person` object?

```
class Person{ 
    constructor()
    {
        // Map person to his nickname
        // should personkey be Person or Integer(personID)?
        // @type {Map<personkey, String>}
        this._personsNicknames = new Map();
    }

    addPersonNickname(person)
    {
        // add to map
    }
}
```

It seems that using `Person` object as a key is a better solution, since I don't expose IDs to `Person` object and only `Room` is responsible for mapping ids to `Person`. But I'm not sure if using a `Person` object as a key for `Map()` is a good idea, it feels like problems with finding a value in a map by an object key can come up and using a plain integer ID as a key wouldn't cause any problems.

And also by using ID as a key I can replace `Map()` with a plain JS object, though I'm not sure wheter it will give any benefits

Comment: Please post a minimal version of how the `Person` object look like. It isn't clear how it is related to `Room` or the `nickname`

Comment: The design looks weird. Why do you need a map to map a person to their nickname? If nicknames are different per room, you'd expect a map that maps rooms to nicknames. And if you're storing nicknames in a `Person` object, why would you ever expect to look up other people's nicknames from that object?